# Getting text stored within a PNG Image in Java

Tags: java, png, java-2d

According to this [Wikipedia entry on the PNG format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Ancillary_chunks), a PNG image file can have embedded text stored in its `tEXt` chunks. This allows storing some text along with the image, which isn't visible in the image itself, but is hidden within the file.

Question is: how can I read these `name=value` pairs from a PNG file using the Java2D api? Does the `ImageReader` class help me here? Can anyone produce a short snippet?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454733/obtain-text-fields-from-a-png-file/10485746#10485746

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible with [javapng](http://code.google.com/p/javapng/).

Use `com.sixlegs.png.PngImage#getTextChunk(String)`.

Answer (score 2):

[PNGJ](http://code.google.com/p/pngj/) library lets you read/write the three types of textual chunks.